# Next url appending right next to the first url while trying to use url rewriting

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I have this simple .htaccess file where i am trying erase the query string from the url.

Current url:- search.php/page?page=1&s=14.

I want to accomplish url:- page/1/14.

so my htaccess file looks like this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^page/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ search.php?page=$1&s=$2
```

and my href looks like this

```
if($i==$page){
    $numbers.='<li><a class="active" href="page/'.$i.'/'.$sterm.'">'.$i.'</a></span></li>';
    }
    else {
        $numbers.='<li><a href="page/'.$i.'/'.$sterm.'">'.$i.'</a></span></li>';
    }
```

which is working fine but however when i am trying to go to page 2 from page 1 my url looks like this :- page/1/14/page/2/14. Why is it happening  ?

Comment: Are you sure you're not just missing a "/" at the start of your href in your link, thus making the browser go to page2 url RELATIVE to the page1 url?

Comment: I have updated my question.However if i use "/" at the start pagination wont seem to work

Comment: Toni, when you call your url it is something like "http://domain.com/page/1/14" right?
And if you change the numbers manually to something like
"http://domain.com/page/2/14" it still works right?
It shouldn't have anything to do with your .htaccess in that case.

Comment: @MartinMouritzen yeah absolutely. if i change that manually it works.so how am i suppose to write those links ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem doesn't have anything to do with your rewrite.

Edit your code to

```
if($i==$page){
    $numbers.='<li><a class="active" href="/page/'.$i.'/'.$sterm.'">'.$i.'</a></span></li>';
}
else {
    $numbers.='<li><a href="/page/'.$i.'/'.$sterm.'">'.$i.'</a></span></li>';
}
```

And it will give the expected result.

Comment: By adding a "/" before my links the pagination won't work.Because it strips out the my base folder from the url. Tried it already

Comment: Ah, but you have to take into account your base folder. So let's say your base folder is "myfolder" then you would make the code something like
if($i==$page){
    $numbers.='<li><a class="active" href="/myfolder/page/'.$i.'/'.$sterm.'">'.$i.'</a></span></li>';
}
else {
    $numbers.='<li><a href="/myfolder/page/'.$i.'/'.$sterm.'">'.$i.'</a></span></li>';
}

Trying to do it relative will just cause a headache. You'd have to set your href to something like "../../../page/".$i."/".$sterm."" which is not very maintainable.

Comment: You're welcome. Also as Ben mentions, please PLEASE if $sterm is a user variable, never output it without running htmlspecialchars() on it first. :)

Answer (score 2):

As MartinMouritzen mentioned, if you have a `href` tag which doesn't start with `/`, it'll use the current path as the base.  In your case the current path is `page/1/14`, so the new path the browser decides to use is `page/1/14/page/2/14`.  Add a leading slash to each `href` attribute should fix this issue.

Additionally you should tweak your rewriteRule a little bit, so it'll allow trailing slashes:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^page/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/?$ search.php?page=$1&s=$2
```

You should also be careful about writing variable straight to HTML, `sterm` seems like it might be user given?  If that's a case it's definitely could be an XSS vulnerability.  You should really just sanitize all variables as they're being written to the page, like this:

```
$s_url = '/page/' . htmlspecialchars($i) . '/' . htmlspecialchars($sterm);
if($i == $page) {
    $numbers .= '<li><a class="active" href="' . $s_url . '">' . htmlspecialchars($i) . '</a></span></li>';
} else {
    $numbers .= '<li><a href="' . $s_url . '">' . htmlspecialchars($i) . '</a></span></li>';
}
```

Lastly, it looks like you have a closing span, but no opening span?  Even though it's technically valid HTML to intertwine tags (aka `<b><i>something</b></i>`), it isn't good form.  You should definitely have the open `span` within the `li` element, or move the closing `span` outside the li element (so the `li` and `span` tags aren't intertwined, only nested).

Comment: Ben martin was right i forgot to select my base folder.And You spotted something i didn't really notice. Thanks for the suggestion.